# How to recognize cubes in a quadratic number field?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

How can I recognize cubes in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{D})$?

I computed $(a + \sqrt{D} b)^3 = (a^3 + 3 D a b^2) + \sqrt{D}(3 a^2 b + D b^3)$ so I can say that  $A + \sqrt{D} B$ is a cube if there exist rationals $a,b$:

- $A = a^3 + 3 D a b^2$
- $B = 3 a^2 b + D b^3$

but this seems hard to solve.

I also noticed that the Norm of a cube must be a rational cube.

Can anybody shed some more light on recognizing cubes. This came up in the context of denesting cubic radicals.

Comment: You are missing some factors of $3$ in your expansion of $(a+\sqrt Db)^3$.

Comment: rain1, they are still missing in the second paragraph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a dirty method.

By multiplying by an integer cube, we may assume that $\alpha=r+s\sqrt D$
is an algebraic integer. Compute numerically $x=(r+s\sqrt D)^{1/3}$
and $y=(r-s\sqrt D)^{1/3}$. Then $x+y$ and $(x-y)/\sqrt D$ must be integers,
so if their numeric values are close to integers, you have a candidate for the
cube root.

Comment: My question is part (d), other parts, –except part (c)– do not matter.

(a) I know how to estimate $(r+s\sqrt D)^{1/3}$, when $D$ is negative; because I know how to estimate $(r+S\sqrt {-1})^{1/3}$; this method is very time-consuming, but it works!

(b) But I don't know how should I find an estimation of $(r+s\sqrt D)^{1/3}$ when $D$ is positive.

(c) I guess that you wrote "*Candidate*", because you consider that in the case of real quadratic fields, the set $\{ m+n\sqrt D | m, n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ is dense. **Is there anything else I haven't considered?**

Comment: (d) $(1987747625+2242968125\sqrt{2})^{1/3}=335+985\sqrt{2}$. The example I gave, maybe is an easy example for computers, because it is enough to check $4$ digits after the decimal separator. For instance, if $r$ and $s$ are such that the distance of $(r+S\sqrt {-1})^{1/3}$ to an integer is less than $10^{-100}$, **what algorithm** do computers use to give output? How do we know we have reached an integer element?